# iterate and Round off in Haskell

Tags: loops, haskell

using iterate function as take 4 (iterate (+0.001) 1.0) , the answer I got is [1.0,1.001,1.0019999999999998,1.0029999999999997]

but want an increment of 0.001 and answer as [1.0,1.001,1.002,1.003] how do round off the value ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you against using a rational number type?

Comment: There simply isn't any number that can be represented as a floating point number that gives you what you want.  0.001 cannot be represented exactly and the next number you can pick that gives a different answer will overshoot the result you want.  Floating point is hard.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Data.Fixed](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/Data-Fixed.html):

```
import Data.Fixed

xs1 = take 4 $ iterate (+0.001) (1.0::Fixed E3)

-- or you can use Enum instance for (Fixed a) also
xs2 = take 4 [1.0::Fixed E3, 1.001..]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with Rational as well as Fixed:

```
x = take 4 $ map (fromRational) [1.000::Rational, 1.001..]
```

That may also be useful, as Rational may be easier to work with, for example:

```
map (logBase 10 . fromRational) $ take 4 [1.000::Rational, 1.001..]
```